# jss and css does not work right after "/"

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter-4

im currently new at CI4 but i've been working with php for a while. so i've been trying to use codeigniter 4 while watching tutorials but i hit a problem where the css and js wont work right after `localhost:8080/something/` at first when i used `localhost:8080/something` it worked. but when i tried `localhost:8080/something/somethingelse`, things doesnt work out.
weirdly enough. when i used `<?= base_url() ?>` it still appeared like this

[image]

but when i erased `<?= base_url()?>` it appeared just fine.

[image]

but still it only worked for `localhost:8080/something` and doesn't work for `localhost:8080/something/somethingelse`. i'm pretty sure the problem is on routing but i dont know how to fix it. any helps would be appreciated

here's my codes

```
     //.env
    app.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/'
    
    database.default.hostname = localhost
    database.default.database = kas_db
    database.default.username = root
    database.default.password = 
    database.default.DBDriver = MySQLi
    
    


    //route
    //this works
    $routes->get('/project', 'project::main');
    //this doesn't
    $routes->get('/project/get', 'project::main');
    
//controller

class project extends BaseController
{

    protected $projectModel;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->projectModel = new ProjectModel();
    }

    public function main()
    {

        $project = $this->projectModel->findAll();
        $data = [
            'title' => 'test',
            'project' => $project
        ];
        
        echo view('project/main',$data);
        echo base_url();

    }   


 //css

<!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Tempusdominus Bbootstrap 4 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css">
  <!-- iCheck -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- JQVMap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap.min.css">
```

Comment: for extra codes i put it here https://www.codepile.net/pile/JjYMAQjG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open App.php file in app/Config folder. Set value for $baseURL variable as below:

```
public $baseURL = 'Your site url;
```

Than in your view

```
<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css'); ?>
```

Comment: Can you please share the url generated

Comment: https://postimg.cc/mtyRHsfq https://postimg.cc/8FNVkX0G https://postimg.cc/yDwHqYFD https://postimg.cc/Hr1q3PHM these are the results

Comment: from what i see the source code for /project and /project/get are the same yet i dont know what makes them different

Comment: nevermind, i found my mistake in the base_url as you said. i forgot to add 'directory' in 'localhost/'